# Как вернуть старое значение input'a

Tags: javascript

Есть input человек вводит что либо и нажимает сохранить, позже решил что то изменить и нажимает на редактировать, меняет текст и резко передумывает его менять, тем самым нажимая отмену. Как сделать так, чтобы отобразился тот текст, который был до редактирования input'a

Answer (score 0):

Заведите переменную, хранящую дефолтный текст, или храните его в `data` атрибуте инпута (смотря на сколько большие данные надо сохранить. Например для числа это вполне катит).

Если пользователь нажал сохранить, то в этот атрибут или переменную заносится текст, а при нажатии на отмену - берётся значение из этой переменной/атрибута